# Magento 2.2.1 - Unable to save changes in product category

Tags: magento2, products, magento-2.2.1

Need your help to assist me on this problem. I have been working on this for almost 3 hour.

I click save button but nothing appear plus the product is not saved.

As my effort..
1) Flush the magento cache
2) clear the cache in browser too
3) restart my laptop

It still doesn't work. Need your help guys..

Comment: I think in product form some attribute values are required, Please check on all field in product form after click on save. if field is required there is error message.

Comment: please provide browser console log after clicking the save button (in Chrome: F12 -> click on "Console"